# Confuse using prepositions ON

Tags: prepositions

> "My father will go through an operation **on** his ear."

This is the sentence. Is this correct?

Comment: @CopperKettle: Grammatical, maybe, but certainly not *idiomatic*. As Khan points out, ***undergo/have*** are valid "alternatives". I'd go a bit further and say they're both "natural" usages, whereas ***go through*** in this context would be extremely unusual phrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thank you! I focused on **on** and slurred over the **go through**.

Comment: @CopperKettle: FWIW, there are more written instances of [he had an ear operation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+had+an+ear+operation%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) than there are of [he had an operation on his ear](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+had+an+operation+on+his+ear%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). (As it happens, I've had dozens of them myself, so I incline to the shorter form just to save my breath when mentioning them in conversation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence sounds correct grammatically.  Alternatively, you can use
undergo or simply have.  My father will undergo/have an operation on his ear.